# Move std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> to std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

Somtimes there is a case that we have a factory that produces a vector of std::unique_ptr and later on we would like share these pointers between classes/threads/you name it. So it would be desirable to use std::shared_ptr instead. There is a way of course to convert std::uniqe_ptr to std::shared_ptr

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sharedV;
std::unique_ptr<int> uniqueV(new int(2));

sharedV = std::move(uniqueV);
```

So is there any straightforward way to do such thing with std collections?

Comment: *So it would be desirable to use std::shared_ptr instead* Do these things need to participate in ownership?  If not you can pass the vector by reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver Desirable for some specific case that we would want to share ownership of these pointers. Don't be overzealous :)

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) from `<algorithm>` to move ranges. It behaves a lot like `std::copy`, but moves instead. The following example will move all `unique_ptr` from `uniqueV` into `sharedV`. `uniqueV`'s elements will all be `nullptr` at the end of the example.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> sharedV;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> uniqueV;

    uniqueV.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(42));

    std::move(uniqueV.begin(), uniqueV.end(), std::back_inserter(sharedV));    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would suggest the [frustratingly] more verbose but also more efficient `sharedV.insert(sharedV.end(), std::make_move_iterator(uniqueV.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(uniqueV.end()))`

Comment: @Barry I was not aware of `std::make_move_iterator`. Very interesting. I would be uncomfortable appending that solution to my answer, I feel it deserves to be a distinct answer.

Comment: Ok, if you insist :)

Answer (score 9):

To add on top of [François Andrieux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45864396/2069064), `std::vector` has a ranged [`insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) member function. Just passing in the iterators to your vector of `unique_ptr` won't work, but there's a way to convert the dereferencing of those iterators from lvalues to xvalues: [`std::move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) and its corresponding factory function: [`std::make_move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator):

```
sharedV.insert(sharedV.end(),
    std::make_move_iterator(uniqueV.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(uniqueV.end()));
```

The reason this may be more efficient than using `std::back_inserter` is that `insert()` will know up front what the resulting size will be, so only at most one allocation needs to be done and then none of the actual insertions need to do size checks.

This is so awkward to write that I would suggest range-based overloads of this named `extend()`:

```
template <class T, class Range>
void extend(std::vector<T>& dst, Range&& range) {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference<Range>{}) {
        dst.insert(dst.end(), begin(range), end(range));
    } else {
        dst.insert(dst.end(),
            std::move_iterator(begin(range)), std::move_iterator(end(range)));
    }
}
```

That's C++17, but is easily doable in C++14. Just takes more typing. You would then write:

```
extend(sharedV, std::move(uniqueV));
```

Comment: I find it far more readable to first resize the target vector and then just the move algorithm (or a for loop). That should be similarly efficient in this case.

Comment: Implementors _could_ make this same optimization with `back_inserter`, right?

Comment: @GManNickG How? By adding overloads of every algorithm taking an output iterator? It's possible I guess, but doesn't seem particularly practical.

Comment: @Barry: I was thinking if the iterators are random access iterators, and the output iterator is a back_inserter, the implementation can additionally check if the container in the back_inserter can `reserve` and if so, call `reserve(std::distance(begin, end))`. Then pass on like normal. It should all be doable at compile-time. Glancing at my favorite implementation, it doesn't seem to do this, though.

Comment: Although on second thought, the permitted operations for `move` may just flat-out prohibit this w.r.t exceptions. Capacity changing for nothing might be undesirable.